# spring rest service capturing audit data

Tags: performance, database-performance, restful-architecture, spring-rest

I have a scenario where a rest service which fetch huge data is persisted into a table. This service is required to execute every hour and if any update or create is found in the response, the respective record should be updated in the database. Given this scenario, for every rest service response I have to query database for every object in the response to find out if there it is an update or create and this would create a multiple round trips to database. This service is a third party service. Please advise if there are any ways to prevent this database round trips from design perspective.

Comment: It is a little big foggy but as a very simple solution you can make batch calls like 20 entities instead of one by one. If you provide a little bit more information we can help you more.

Comment: well, I will be more clear. I have service which will fetch a response of nearly 20K-50K objects in a response. Currently, we are storing the objects in a list using hibernate and looping the list to identify the existence of a record for update. Question is could there be a better way than storing objects in a list since if later the response is 1L, the size of the list again grows. would it be a good approach to store such huge data in the list?

Comment: Just to be clear you are getting 50K objects from an external source, putting it to a list, iterating it one by one by making a db call to check if it is updated or not that means you are making 50K calls. And you want to reduce the number of calls you are making.

Comment: yes. correct. As it is a data from external source, today we have 50K max and possibility of data getting intensified to 1L also is true.

Comment: Why don't you just send them to db for the update instead of checking it ? Regardless of the answer I still think that you can do that in batch like retrieving 100 rows per call which will provide you a big boost in terms of performance.

Comment: Just to be more clear in understanding, you are suggesting to iterate and read the objects in a list in chunks of 100 and pass it to the database and once the iteration is completed, I can nullify the list of 50K or 1L size, right. As another approach, when you say send them to database, you referring to use procedures or functions?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167303/discussion-between-skanda-and-cool).